# open() error File exists even if O_EXCL is removed

Tags: c, linux

I have the simple part of code that tries to open the file or create a new one:

```
desc = open(path, 0600 | O_RDWR | O_CREAT);
if (desc == -1){
    fprintf(stderr, "process %d: open: ", i);
    perror("");
}
```

But even without `O_EXCL` I get an error "File exists"

```
process: open: File exists
```

So what's the matter of this issue could be?

Comment: `open(path, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0600)` - The mode should be supplied as the third argument.

Comment: What is `0600` doing there?

Comment: So as it turns out, O_EXCL is 0200.  By ORing 0600, you *are* specifying O_EXCL =]

Comment: ```int open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode);``` You misplaced the arguments.

Comment: Thank you) My example was writen by my school teacher 0_0 I should tell him that He's doing wrong